# Multiprocessing Early Exit

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a loop that is checking for the first instance of a value that evaluates to `True`:

```
for i in l:
    if fun(i):
        return i
return None
```

I'd like to speed this up using a multiprocessing pool, but my understanding is that pooling would just run `fun` over every element in `l`. Is there a way to do a sort of "short-circuit" when pooling?

Comment: Will stuff break if you run `fun` on elements after the first true output? If later evaluations have to wait for earlier ones to finish like that, it's going to put a pretty big damper on how much you can benefit from multiprocessing.

Comment: @user2357112 no, nothing will break, but there's no point in evaluating everything since I'm only searching for the first instance that evaluates to True.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the `terminate` method is for, but you have to be careful how you use it. It will kill the worker processes, but surprisingly it won't stop you from blocking forever on a waiting call. So you can only use it if you do `apply_async` or `imap_unordered` calls. Closing from another thread typically causes your calls into the pool to hang. In this example I set `chunksize` to 1 which is the preferred value if a single work item has a significant amount of processing. You can set `chunksize` to something greater if work item cost is low and you don't mind processing more items before you are done. But don't use the default... must items will be processed before anything makes it back to you.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(item):
    print(item)
    return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        for i in pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(100), chunksize=1):
            if i == 10:
                print('terminate')
                pool.terminate()
                break
    print('done')
```

Comment: When would I use apply_async vs imap_unordered? It's not obvious to me fro the documentation.

Comment: @Teknophilia - `Pool.apply_async()` gives you more control (you get the process itself, not just its potential return value) but in this case it's an overkill which is why I deleted my answer.

Comment: `imap_unordered` is a higher level interface - think of it as a wrapper on top of `apply_async` (well... close enough). Suppose you have 1 million items. You have to call `apply_async` on each of them and you have to keep each result object and then wait on that object to get a result. `imap_unordered` takes a list or generator and keeps track of the individual calls down to the the pool for you. And its the only one of the map calls that passes results back immediately as they are available. The others wait.

Comment: @Teknophilia - I haven't tested with `apply_async` but I am concerned about what happens to a thread waiting on its `AsyncResult` object when the pool is terminated. Does the pool clean this object up? Seeing how dismally fragile it is in other cases (for instance, continuing to iterate on `imap_unordered` after termination just hangs), I wouldn't hold out hope!